# Issues with dynamodb query with KeyConditionExpression

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Trying to use KeyConditionExpression  as per the dynamodb api [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property) using nodejs sdk. KeyConditionExpression is not supported with nodejs SDK.

Here is what i did

Created a Table with Hash and Range.

```
Table : TABLE1
Hash Attribute Name : Provider ( String) 
Range Attribute Key : ScheduledEndTime ( Number ) // In Milli Seconds
```

Here is payload to trigger dynamo DB query:

```
{
  TableName: 'TABLE1',
  ConsistentRead: true,
  Select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
  KeyConditionExpression: 'Provider = :v_provider AND ScheduledEndTime > :v_scheduledEndTime',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":v_provider": {
      S: "amazon"
    },
    ":v_scheduledEndTime": {
      N: "10"
    }
  }
};
```

But, the above payload thrown below errors

```
[Error: MultipleValidationErrors: There were 2 validation errors:
* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'KeyConditions' in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'KeyConditionExpression' found in    params]
[Error: MultipleValidationErrors: There were 2 validation errors:
* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'KeyConditions' in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'KeyConditionExpression' found in params]
```

As per the document, if we use KeyConditionExpression, SDK should not consider the KeyConditions key and I tried with latest nodejs sdk as well. 
Is there any thing wrong in the payload pattern ?

Answer (score 4):

I think some places (Lambda in particular) give you the wrong version of the API by default. When I was running into this problem, replacing my dynamo instance with the following fixed the problem:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
```